# Economic potential of a company

Tags: terminology, business-language

I would like to say, in business terms, `"thanks to the money the company has"`, meaning they can make investments,

I thought of: 
`Thanks to your company's economic potential` ?

Comment: You probably mean *solvency, liquidity* or *assets*, or indeed any number of other alternatives, but it is hard to tell without further context. Thanks to the money the company has *what*?

Comment: i mean, thanks to their potential to make investments, they can afford to...bla bla

Comment: Maybe you can use the word "Resources".

Answer (score 1):

Going by your comment, you mean *free capital* (see e.g. [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/free-capital.html), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/free%20capital)). *Economic potential* is too wishy-washy, as it could mean other things.

Comment: CAPITAL would be the term +1